# Netgear router DNS issues, config page inaccessible

Tags: windows, networking, router, dns

I have a netgear WNDR4500v2 router, which for the last several months has been having strange DNS-related(?) issues.

For several months, routerlogin.net and http://192.168.1.1 (the current gateway) have directed to an error page saying the connection was reset. Netgear genie software is also unable to access the router setup or even detect the model/name.

I attempted a factory reset last week, after which the router blocked all name resolution as well as continuing to block access to the config page.

The only program that can connect through the router is skype, due to using a static IP address instead of a server domain name.

This behavior is exhibited for all wired and unwired devices.

If the router is unplugged, a direct wired connection to the modem functions normally.

So far i have attempted changing the modem internal IP address, as someone suggested the devices could have identical IPs. I do not think this is possible, and predictably nothing happened (modem internal IP is currently 192.168.255.1).

I have changed the preferred DNS servers for local area connection to the router IP address, default gateway, automatic, and google DNS (just to see what happens) with utterly no changes.

OSes involved: windows 7, windows 10, mint 17, iOS (unknown version) - it cant be an OS-specific issue on the computer-end.

Comment: This is not a DNS issue, connecting directly to an IP address has nothing to do with DNS... are you sure your computer is getting an IP address? What is your output relates to your Local Area Network adapter of `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: Yes, it has everything to do with DNS. names need to be looked up via DNS, IP addresses do not. Anything that requires a DNS lookup simply hangs at "looking up <whatever>" or "resolving".


My computer is very definitely getting an IP address, but the grammar in _italic_What is your output relates to your Local Area Network adapter of ipconfig /all?_italic_  makes no sense...

Comment: You said that `http://192.168.1.1` did not work, that has nothing to do with DNS, Your browser is hanging at "resolving" because that is the first step... that is a symptom, not a definitive problem, combined with the fact that direct IP connections do not work it suggests a bigger problem. You need to get to the command line and find out, what is your IP, subnet, DNS server, can you ping your router or a public DNS server, what does a traceroute show, etc...

Comment: In the Windows start menu, type `cmd` and press enter, a command prompt window should open, at the command prompt enter `ipconfig /all` and add the resulting output related to your Local Area Network adapter to your original post. If you don't provide more information, we cannot help you. In Linux you could post the output of `ifconfig eth0` and `netstat -nr`

Comment: I have already done this, i am an experienced user. The subnet mask it definitely correct, and matches the internal IP of the router.
Pings to the router work normally. I am not saying the inability to access the router config is a DNS issue, just the inability to access any other websites without a direct IP address.

Comment: Fine... I guess my 25+ years experience as a technician and all the training and experience I have in networking is wrong and I am an idiot and have no idea how to troubleshoot this from cradle to grave. Good luck to you.

Comment: @confusedpenguin You keep saying 'subnet mask' in ways that make me think you don't know what the subnet mask is.  _"192.168.1.1 (the current subnet mask)"_, _"I have changed the preferred DNS servers ... to the subnet mask"_, _"The subnet mask it definitely correct, and matches the internal IP of the router."_  Your subnet mask should (most likely) be 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Oh, that is quite silly of me. default gateway, not subnet mask (which was 255.255.255.0 last i checked yesterday, and always has been). i knew that sounded wrong to my tired, confused brain.

@acejavelin, i am not saying you are wrong, you just clearly failed to even read the entire post before commenting. I have no issues connecting directly to an IP with the exception of the router itself.

Comment: _"modem internal IP address is 192.168.255.1"_  Is your modem also acting as a router, or is it set up in bridge mode?  What is the external (WAN) IP of your WNDR4500v2 router?